# Twisted TCP server serve UDP requests

Tags: python, twisted

I have a server using a TCP-based protocol written in Twisted, and would like a specific request from that server to do something using a UDP-based protocol, then return the result of the UDP call back to the TCP client. The responses will be out of order, which is fine, and doing a UDP request is easy by just keeping a reference to the UDP protocol/factory/whatever in the TCP protocol instance, but I'm unsure how to actually implement the do-something-on-response part.

Also, as I haven't really worked with UDP in Twisted before, I'm not entirely sure how it works (regarding the differences between UDP and TCP). Would I need a factory that spawns a new UDP protocol instance per request, have one instance per server the UDP part will interact with, or just have one instance that will send/receive to/from all servers the UDP part will interact with? I currently only have a regular library for the UDP protocol, but will write a Twisted protocol around that based on answers to that part of the question.

I'm unsure if I've explained my requirements well, so an overview of what I'm making:

- Clients connect to a TCP-based protocol and issue requests (JSON format)
- Certain requests ask us to query a UDP server (e.g. a game server's status info) and return the results
- The same client may request several queries at once, which is supported as the response will contain information relating to the original request.

Comment: Have you read UDP networking documentation in twisted: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/udp.html? I definitely suggest you to read this.